# Is it possible to search subpages by subpagename

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to see if there is a possibility to have CirrusSearch index subpages by their subpagename and not just the fullpagename. Reason is that these subpages are hard to find when just using the little searchbar in the top right corner of mediawiki.
For example a page called `folder1/myTool` is only found when starting the search with any part of `folder1` versus being able to search for `myTool`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and set `$wgCirrusSearchCompletionProfiles = 'fuzzy-subphrases'` in you LocalSettings.php

on Mediawiki.org try to search for 'portal' you can see it is working there as you get the 'VisualEditor/Portal' in the result, here you can see all the config options in use on Mediawiki.org :  https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-config-dump&formatversion=2